# $s(t)=\frac{-30 e^{\frac{-2t}{5}} (2 \cos 5t - 25 \sin 5t)+1947}{629}$

Tags: integration, functions, derivatives, problem-solving

> A mobile moves horizontally on the $x$-axis (graduated in meters). Its
>   speed as a function of time is given by $v(t) = 6 e^{\frac{-2t}{5}}
>  \cos 5t$ and its initial position is $s (0) = 3$. Determine its final
>   position and the distance it will have travelled.

Could anyone be able to complete this exercise? I'd like to confirm what I've done so far.

The position is $s(t)=\frac{-30 e^{\frac{-2t}{5}} (2 \cos 5t - 25 \sin 5t)+1947}{629}$.

Do I have to compute the time when the speed is $0$ for the final position and use the  arc length ($\int_a^b \sqrt{1+f(t)^2} dt$) to compute the distance travelled? The answers I've obtained are $3.09214$ for the position and $3.18954$ for the distance travelled.

Comment: Note that the position at time $T$ is given by $s(t)-s(0)=\int_0^Tv(t)dt.$ Y

Comment: Is the final answer close to 9.55?

Comment: I don't have the final answer as solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may define distance travelled $s(t)$ as

$$s(t) =\int_{t_i}^{t_f}|v(t)|dt$$

So you have to split the integral wherever $v(t)=0$

If you have to find the total distance travelled starting from $t = 0$ to $t \to \infty$,

$$S=\int_{0}^{\infty}|v(t)| dt$$

I computed $S$ on Wolfram Alpha and it came out to be close to 9.55:

[image]

For finding final position, you may compute:

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{-30 e^{\frac{-2t}{5}} (2 \cos 5t - 25 \sin 5t)+1947}{629}$$

which comes out to be $\frac{1947}{629}$.

Comment: Could you display a full answer to this question? Could you tell me how to find the final position?

Comment: I computed the antiderivative and found it to be the same as you got. Also realize that sum of differences between successive extremas of $s(t)$ gives the total distance travelled in one dimension. In this case, it is not possible to calculate the total distance travelled by hand, since there are infinitely many points where $v(t) = 0$. You may use a computer algebra system.

Comment: Formally, does the final position should be 3.09214 m? What is your answer?

Comment: How did you get $3.09214$? I got $\frac{1947}{629} \approx 3.0954$

Comment: I messed up the calculation. I did exactly the same thing. Could you explicit the full steps for the distance travelled?

Comment: @SandraRoss I think i should not attempt to solve this by hand, because as i said the modulus sign will of the integral will need to be broken up according to intervals where $v(t)$ is positive or negative. There will be infinite terms, alternating positive and negative! Its better that you calculate it using a CAS like Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Could you at least develop a bit I could compute it? What is your answer if you use wolfram alpha?

Comment: Why don't using $\int_a^b \sqrt{1+f(t)^2} dt$ for $a=0$ and $b=\infty$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49602/discussion-between-max-payne-and-sandra-ross).